# Split a vector by given values of an another vector

Tags: matlab, vector, split

Lets say we've following vectors:

```
data =[12,343,63,3636,63,6363,636,363,63,346];
index=[1 3;4 8; 9 10];
```

What i now want to do is to split the vector `data` after the index values of the vector `index` without a loop,so that it looks like that:

```
matrix=    12   343 63   0   0
           3636 63  6363 636 363
           63   346 0    0   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
nx = max(index(:,2) - index(:,1)) + 1; % X-dimension of result
result = zeros(size(index, 1), nx) % Preallocate result
for k=1:size(index,1)
   n = index(k,2) - index(k,1) + 1; % Number of elements in this batch
   result(k,1:n) = data(index(k,1):index(k,2)); % Copy element
end
```

Comment: The OP haws said "without a loop".

Comment: Oops, did not see that. I am not sure there is a loop-free solution though. And the OP obviously thought the answer was OK since he accepted it ;)

Comment: I would love to see a loop-free version though. Someone up for the task?